# RegEx to get section of URL after string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following URL:

```
http://data.test.com/api/v1/entity/1231
```

And I need to get the text that is after `v1/` and before `/` (between the slashes), in this case the word `entity`. I'm using the following regex, but what I get back is `entity/1231` on group 1:

```
/^[^\#\?]+\/v1\/([^\?]+).*$/
```

Any idea on how to get rid of `1231` or anything that comes after `entity`?

Comment: `v1\/([^/]+)` or `v1\/(.*?)\/`

Comment: If the parts are fixed `"http://data.test.com/api/v1/entity/1231".split("/")[5]`

Comment: If the URLs you're working with are that predictable then regular expressions, while possible, may be an overly-complex tool for the job. Are the URLs changeable? Will it always be "*after `v1/` and before [the next] `/`*"?

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes, they are predictable

Comment: You need `str.match(/\/v1\/([^\/]+)/)[1]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may **capture the value you need into a capturing group** with `new RegExp("/v1/([^/]+)"`:

```js
var str = "http://data.test.com/api/v1/entity/1231";
var res = str.match(new RegExp("/v1/([^/]+)"));
if (res) 
    console.log(res[1]);
```

The `/v1/([^/]+)` matches:

- `/v1/` - a literal string `/v1/`
- `([^/]+)` - capturing group 1 matching one or more chars other than `/`.

Thanks to the constructor notation in the RegExp definition, there is no need to escape forward slashes in the regex pattern.

Alternatively, since ECMAScript 2018 enabled lookbehind usage in the JavaScript *RegExp* patterns, you can also use a **lookbehind-based approach** to get the value you need directly as a whole match:

```js
const str = "http://data.test.com/api/v1/entity/1231";
const res = str.match(/(?<=\/v1\/)[^\/]+/);
if (res) {
    console.log(res[0]);
}
```

*Details*:

- `(?<=\/v1\/)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `/v1/` text
- `[^\/]+` - one or more chars other than a `/` char.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
^[^\#\?]+\/v1\/([^\?]+).*(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/1231)$
```